# Implicitly passing in values from containing classes into the classes fields?

Tags: scala, implicits

Consider a class School.
If we were to add a Pupil field to the school class is it possible to implicity pass a reference to the School object into the Pupil object.

So rather than doing

```
class School() {
   val pupil:Pupil = new Pupil(this)
}
```

We could do this

```
class School() {
   val pupil:Pupil = new Pupil()
}
```

And would still be able to access the school reference from the pupil object. I'm thinking scala implicits might help?

Comment: Perhaps you've scaled down the example so much that it is no longer representative, but are you sure this isn't a situation where explicit is better than implicit?

Answer (score 1):

For example,

```
object ImplicitConstructorParameter extends App {
  class Pupil(implicit val school: School)

  class School {
    implicit val school: School = this
    val pupil: Pupil = new Pupil
  }

  val school = new School

  println(school.pupil.school.eq(school))
}
```

prints `true`